# mySQL - Find Trees in DB that have been Dead for 5 years?

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering if there is a more concise way of finding trees that have had a Vigor rating of 6, 8 or 9 for the past 5 years.

In the past, I was looking trees dead only for the past two years, and I used a query like this:

```
set @sampleyear = 2020;
select *
from tblTree
where tblTree.Year=@sampleyear
and (((Year = @sampleyear) and (Vigor not in (6,8,9))) or ((Year = (@sampleyear-1)) and (Vigor not in (6,8,9))));
```

I could expand the last line to just continue back for 5 years, but I was wondering if anyone could think of a better way?

Thank you!

Sample data could look like this, the query would return rows with year 2020 and tree id 1 but not 2:

| tree id | year | vigor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015 | 1 |
| 1 | 2016 | 1 |
| 1 | 2017 | 1 |
| 1 | 2018 | 6 |
| 1 | 2019 | 6 |
| 1 | 2020 | 6 |
| 2 | 2015 | 6 |
| 2 | 2016 | 6 |
| 2 | 2017 | 6 |
| 2 | 2018 | 6 |
| 2 | 2019 | 6 |
| 2 | 2020 | 6 |

Comment: Can you provide sample data and which ones you would select, and why?

Comment: @ScottHunter added some!

Comment: *Why* would the query "return rows with year 2020 and tree id 1 but not 2"?

Comment: Personally not in favour of retyping all your data so perhaps read [how not to use pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data.

Comment: Please would you add a more concise explanation of how you want to identify a tree as dead. Is it trees which have had a vigor rating of 6, 8 or 9 for all of the last 5 years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing query does not make much sense. Here it is with `@sampleyear` expanded:

```sql
select *
from tblTree
where tblTree.Year = 2020
and (
    (Year = 2020 and Vigor not in (6,8,9)) or
    (Year = 2019 and Vigor not in (6,8,9)) -- this can never be true as you have tblTree.Year = 2020 outside this group
);
```

Which is the same as just:

```sql
select *
from tblTree
where tblTree.Year = 2020
and Vigor not in (6,8,9);
```

This is the basic extension of your existing query, just using `>=` comparison for the year instead of listing them explicitly and grouping so as to return just the list of tree_ids:

```sql
/* Any years >= 2018 Vigor NOT IN (6, 8, 9) */
SELECT `tree_id`
FROM `tblTree`
WHERE `year` >= YEAR(NOW()) - 5
AND `vigor` NOT IN (6, 8, 9)
GROUP BY `tree_id`;
```

These are variations on this theme, which you may find useful:

```sql
/* All years >= 2018 Vigor IN (6, 8, 9) */
SELECT `tree_id`
FROM `tblTree`
WHERE `year` >= YEAR(NOW()) - 5
GROUP BY `tree_id`
HAVING MIN(`vigor` IN (6, 8, 9)) = 1;

/* All years >= 2018 Vigor NOT IN (6, 8, 9) */
SELECT `tree_id`
FROM `tblTree`
WHERE `year` >= YEAR(NOW()) - 5
GROUP BY `tree_id`
HAVING MIN(`vigor` NOT IN (6, 8, 9)) = 1;

/* Any years >= 2018 Vigor IN (6, 8, 9) */
SELECT `tree_id`
FROM `tblTree`
WHERE `year` >= YEAR(NOW()) - 5
AND `vigor` IN (6, 8, 9)
GROUP BY `tree_id`;
```

Any of these queries can be easily joined back to the full table if you want to see the full records for the time span being looked at:

```sql
SELECT `tblTree`.*
FROM (

    /* query from above */
    /* all years >= 2018 Vigor IN (6, 8, 9) */
    SELECT `tree_id`
    FROM `tblTree`
    WHERE `year` >= YEAR(NOW()) - 5
    GROUP BY `tree_id`
    HAVING MIN(`vigor` IN (6, 8, 9)) = 1
    /* end query from above */

) t
JOIN `tblTree`
    ON `t`.`tree_id` = `tblTree`.`tree_id`
    AND `tblTree`.`year` >= YEAR(NOW()) - 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by comparing `YEAR` and `NOW` subtracting an arbitrary `interval` set by you.  IE

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE YEAR(NOW() - interval 7 year) > `year`;
```

A side note, you should not name your field `year` in your table.  This is a reserved function in MySQL.  You can "get around" it by putting it in ticks

```
`year`
```

Which using ticks is always best practice, but it's even *better* practice to use the ticks AND not use reserved functions as names for your fields.